jsRegexpString makes syntax highlighting so slow
I have some javascript files with hard coded base64 strings, and there is horrible lag between cursor commands.
When I did a syntime report, I am seeing:
  3.553307000 589   38      0.196905000   0.006032779 jsRegexpString \%(\%(\<return\|\<typeof\|\_[^)\]'"[:blank:][:alnum:]_$]\)\s*\)\@<=/\ze[^*/]
  0.034516000 2660  2147    0.000037000   0.000012976 jsComment      //

Is there anything I can do to fix this?
Both set re=0 and set re=1 make no real difference.

I would do:
:set synmaxcol=300

It limits syntax highlighting to the first 300 columns. In my experience it improves considerabmy the performance of syntax highlighting.
